# Multiple async/await chaining

Tags: c#, async-await

How to make multiple async/await chaining in C#?
For example, *start few HTTP requests and then do not wait all of them, but start new request after each completed*?

Comment: I would turn each request into a seperate thread, and then have a callback that these threads can call back into the main app to queue them.  Taking care to lock before you insert into the queue, and before you pull out.

Comment: I want to use async/await to avoid using multiple threads.

Comment: @GREnvoy: The whole point of Tasks is to stop thinking in terms of threads. There is a Task answer to this question, and the system can do any necessary threading better than you can.

Comment: @Chrome See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22036708/1906557). max 20 tasks are downloading at any time, and as soon as one finishes a new task is started..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to write an `async` method:

```
async Task DownloadAndFollowupAsync(...)
{
  await DownloadAsync();
  await FollowupAsync();
}
```

Which you can then use with `await Task.WhenAll`:

```
await Task.WhenAll(DownloadAndFollowupAsync(...),
    DownloadAndFollowupAsync(...));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to perform some `async` action on a collection of items with a limited degree of parallelism, then probably the simplest way is to use [`ActionBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684) from TPL Dataflow, since it supports `async` delegates (unlike most other parallel constructs in TPL, like `Parallel.ForEach()`).

```
var block = new ActionBlock<string>(
    url => DownloadAsync(url),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = few });

foreach (var url in urls)
    block.Post(url);

block.Complete();
await block.Completion;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method of Tasks for this purpose or [the extension that takes a Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx) and is used to return results.

Comment: Probably because `ContinueWith` is dangerous in `async` code; you should use `await` instead.

Comment: @StephenCleary You can always use ConfigureAwait to avoid deadlocks. You just have to be a bit more careful.

Comment: The "dangerous" use I'm referring to is the way that `ContinueWith` defines its default task scheduler, and the fact that it doesn't naturally propagate exceptions/cancellation, nor resume in a captured context automatically. `await` should be the default choice in >99% of cases.

Comment: @StephenCleary ran into an issue you warned about. The task resulting of continuewith was never running to completion according to it's status. Separate awaits fixed it.